# Git integration with Windows Explorer for the user account

Tags: git, explorer

I have installed latest Git (Git-1.9.5-preview20150319) from admin account on Windows 7. Git has integrated with Windows Explorer (Git Init Here, Git Gui, Git Bash in the pop-up menu) on admin account.

On the user account Git Bash and Git Gui work, but they are not integrated with Windows Explorer. How can i achieve it?

Comment: did you installed it with option "All users" or "current user" (last one is the default IIRC) ?

Comment: i haven't seen such option.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

Uninstall your current Git from Windows.

Go to [GIT download page](http://git-scm.com/download/win) -> Download Will Start Automatically

If you don’t want to go through the above clicks, here is the direct url to the download page on [msysgit page](http://msysgit.github.io/).

Click on the downloaded executable to start the install process. Accept all the default options during installation as shown below.

The installation wizard will walk you through the following 10 screens:

**1) Welcome Screen**

**2) Read the license**

**3) Select Destination folder:** By default this will be installed under `“C:\Program Files\Git”`

**4) Select Components:** This lets you choose which components of git you like to install. Use the default selections.

[image]

**5) Select Start Menu Folder**

**6) Adjusting your PATH environment:** Use the default selection “Use Git Bash Only”.

**[Note]** - In Your case use Run git from Windows Command Prompt.

[image]

**7) Choosing the SSH executable:** Use the default selection “Use OpenSSH”.

**8) Configuring the line ending conversions:** This indicates how Git will treat the line ending in the text files. If you are planning to checkout files from a remote Git repository that is running on Linux, use the default selection “Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings”.

[image]

**9) Installing:** This will show the progress bar indicating the installation progress.

**10) Completing the Git setup wizard:** Click on finish to exist the setup.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I've followed default settings. I have chosen "Use Git Bash Only", but that does not disturb Git integration on the admin account.

Comment: @user2314351See the Step 6 "[Note] - In Your case use Run git from Windows Command Prompt."

Comment: @user2314351 Can you try this https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/ and let me know if this solves your problem.